# Scroll with multiple, and going different directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have a large image of an L-shaped painting on one page. I created divs over parts of the painting I want to explain. When the page loads, I want it to scroll down the length of the image, and then move to the left of the image, stopping at each div for a few seconds. I understand how to get the page to scroll down on load, but I do not understand how to continue scrolling once it has reached the first div. Should I target the data-box and not the class, so it will continue to move through each div box?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".bird1").offset().top
    }, 5000);
    
});
```

```css
/*font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yellowtail|Calligraffitti|Courgette);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,300italic);



body {
 /*background-color: #fbf2e0;*/
 background-color: #fcf5e9;
 /*background-color: #fdfbf5;*/
 /*background-color: #fefcf8;*/
 font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
}



/************************************
   HOME PAGE
************************************/
.jumbotronOne { 
   background: 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(50,50,50, 0.8),
      rgba(50,50,50, 0.8)
    ),
    url(https://scontent-ord1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xft1/v/t1.0-9/11150883_878883265488069_6626923622401519037_n.jpg?oh=d5636fb2a9b2e8365a8c951037d70895&oe=55FDD666);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 margin-top:3.6em;

 /*-webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;*/
}

.words {
 color: #fdf8ef;
 padding-top: 9%;
 background:linear-gradient;
}

.red {
    color:lightcoral;
 }
#title {
 font-family: Courgette;
 text-align: center;

}

#text {
 text-align: center;
 width: 95%;
 padding-top: 5%;
 line-height: 150%;
 font-size: 25px;
}



/************************************
   NAV TRANSPARENT
************************************/



#nav {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

/*** ACTIVE COLOR ***/
.navbar ,.active,.sr-only{
   background-color: transparent;
   background: transparent;
   border-bottom-color: lightcoral;
   border-bottom-width: 5px;
   border-top: none;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar li a { 
 color: #fff; 
} 



/*nav color*/
.navbar-header,.collapse, .navbar-collapse , .navbar-toggle, .navbar-right, .dropdown, .dropdown-menu, .navbar-brand,.navbar-brand, .dropdown-toggle, .button {
 background-color: rgba(251,251,253, .5);
}



/*IMG SIZING*/
#header img {
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
 right:100%; 
}

.slideIn {
    top:-100px;
}
  
.navbar-fixed-top {
 transition:all 1s ease-in-out
}
/*nav font color*/
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
   /*color: black; */
}


/*hover class text color */

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
   color: inherit;

 }


li #activeColor.active { 
 background-color:red; 
}


/************************************
   ARTIST PAGE
************************************/

/*profile*/
#noPadding{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.noPadding {
 padding: 0;
 margin:0;

}
.profile img {
 object-fit:cover;
 display: block;
 height: 300px;
 width: 400px;
 margin-top: 15%;
 top: 5%;

}

.artistHeader {
   /*color: black;*/
   margin-top: 7%;
  }

.longName {
   font-size: 20px;
  }





/************************************
   MEANING
************************************/

.redBox {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 /*left:-75px;*/
 top:5px;
}

.redBox div {
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: red;
 position: relative;
}

/*.totem .ganesh .bird1 .bird2 .katy .fredia .saar .parks .james .anna .ai .friends1 .friends2 .friends3 .kids .parents .quote{
 display: none;
}*/
.meaningImg img {
 margin-top: 1.1%;
 max-height:1000px;
 max-width:1000em;
 margin-bottom: 0; 
}
.totem {
 height: 160px;
 width: 60px;
 top: 412px;
 left: 220px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.ganesh {
 top: 420px;
 left: 210px;
 height:140px;
 width:80px;
}

.bird1{
 top: 287px;
 left: 310px;
 height:40px;
 width:250px; 
}
.katy{
 top: 160px;
 left: 635px;
 height:200px;
 width:244px; 
}
.fredia{
 top: 125px;
 left: 960px;
 height:194px;
 width:158px; 
}
.saar{
 top: -215px;
 left: 1150px;
 height:194px;
 width:158px; 
}
.parks{ 
 top: -255px;
 left: 1350px;
 height:168px;
 width:122px; 
}
.james{
 top: -505px;
 left: 1690px;
 height:358px;
 width:122px; 
}
.anna{
 top: -780px;
 left: 2005px;
 height:290px;
 width:146px; 
}
.andy{
 top: -1030px;
 left: 2305px;
 height:255px;
 width:140px; 
}
.ai{
 top: -1315px;
 right: -2500px;
 height:249px;
 width:514px;
 /*508 & 243 */
}
.friends1{
 top:-1450px;
 right:-3175px;
 height:109px;
 width:264px;
}
.friends2{
 top:-1550px;
 right:-3855px;
 height:103px;
 width:200px;
}
.friends3{
 top:-1800px;
 right:-3685px;
 height:97px;
 width:164px;
}
.kids{
 top:-1870px;
 right:-3185px;
 height:109px;
 width:295px;
}
.parents{
 top:-1890px;
 right:-3475px;
 height:203px;
 width:358px;
}

.quote{
 top:-2250px;
 right:-4200px;
 height:230px;
 width:250px;
}
.bird2{
 top:-2550px;
 right:-3950px;
 height:250px;
 width:240px;
}

.totem, .ganesh, .bird1, .bird2, .katy, .fredia, .saar, .parks, .james, .anna, .andy, .ai, .friends1, .friends2, .friends3, .kids, .parents, .quote {
    opacity:0;   
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
}

.totem:hover, .ganesh:hover, .bird1:hover, .bird2:hover, .katy:hover, .fredia:hover, .saar:hover, .parks:hover, .james:hover, .andy:hover, .anna:hover, .ai:hover, .friends1:hover, .friends2:hover, .friends3:hover, .kids:hover, .parents:hover, .quote:hover {
    opacity:1;
    
}
.background {
   background: 
  linear-gradient(
  rgba(219,253,244, 0.7),
  rgba(219,253,244, 0.7)
  ),
  url(http://wallpoper.com/images/00/43/13/34/forest-sunrise-wallpaper-landscape-nature_00431334.jpg);
 /*background-size: length;*/
 width: 4892px;

/* SINGLE TREE url(http://wallpoper.com/images/00/42/56/25/forest-summer_00425625.jpg);*/
/* TRESS LIGHT GREEN url(http://wallpaperlepi.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Awesome-Nature-Ray-of-Light-Wallpaper.jpg);*/
/* TREES LIGHT GREEN url(http://orig12.deviantart.net/ddf1/f/2012/303/0/0/forest_stock_by_dl_stockandresources-d5jffdv.jpg);*/
/* RED TINT url(http://wallpoper.com/images/00/43/13/34/forest-sunrise-wallpaper-landscape-nature_00431334.jpg);*/
/*  
  LIGHT GREEN COLOR  */

/*  rgba(216,74,74, 0.1),
  rgba(216,74,74, 0.1)
  RED COLOR    */

 height:50%;
 margin-top: 0;
 /*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
 /*background-size: cover;*/
 /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
  }

  
/************************************
   FOOTER
************************************/
#footer {
 color: #ED5565;
 background-color: #fbf2e0;
 /*background-color: #fcf5e9;*/
 
 text-align: center;
 /*margin-top: 20em;*/
 /*max-height: 1%;*/
 /*height:10%;*/
 /*padding-bottom: 15;*/
 margin-bottom: 0; 

}


/*****************************
    PIC GALLERY 
*****************************/
.fullDrawing {
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-top: 50px;
 max-height:200.750em;/*18.750em;/*height: 300px;*/
 max-width:1000em; /*91.500em;*/ /*120px*/
 min-height: 13em;
 width: 100%;
}
.bottomFullDrawing {
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-top: 50px;
 max-height:200.750em;/*18.750em;/*height: 300px;*/
 max-width:1000em; /*91.500em;*/ /*120px*/
 min-height: 13em;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 2.5em ; 
}
.galleryContainer {
 width: 90%;
 overflow-x:scroll;
 overflow-y:hidden;
 padding-top: 5%;
 padding-left: 5%;
 padding-right: 5%;

}

.profile {
 margin-top: 5%;
}

.galleryContainer img {
 /*height: 171px;*/
 /*width: 180px;*/
 /*margin-top: 100%;*/
 /*padding-bottom: 0px;*/
    /*height: 515px;*/

}

.galleryContainer img {
 height: 300px;
 width: 400px;
 object-fit:cover;
}


.fullDrawing img{
 height: 217.273px;
 width:1440px;
}


.list-inline {
 white-space:nowrap;
}


.galleryContainer > .row [class*="col-lg"], .galleryContainer > .row [class*="col-md"], .galleryContainer > .row [class*="col-md"] {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:normal;
    vertical-align:top;
  }
  #main-content > .row {
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
  }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- totem pole -->
    <div class="redBox">
        
            <div class=" box totem">
                <span class="hoverTotem" data-box="totem" ></span>
            </div>


        <!-- ganesh -->
        <div class="focus box ganesh">
            <span data-box="ganesh" ></span>
        </div>
        <!-- BIRD 1 -->
        <div class="box bird1">
            <span data-box="bird1" ></span>
        </div>
        <!-- KATY -->
        <div class="box katy">
            <span data-box="katy" ></span>
        </div>
        <!-- FREDIA -->
        <div class="box fredia">
            <span data-box="fredia" ></span>
        </div>   

        <!-- sarry -->
        <div class="box saar">
            <span data-box="saar" ></span>
        </div>

        <!-- parks -->
        <div class="box parks">
            <span data-box="parks" ></span>
        </div>

        <!-- james -->
        <div class="box james">
            <span data-box="james" ></span>
        </div> 

        <!-- ANNA -->
        <div class="box anna">
            <span data-box="anna" ></span>
        </div>  

        <!-- ANDY -->
        <div class="box andy">
            <span data-box="andy" ></span>
        </div> 

        <!-- AI -->
        <div class="box ai">
            <span data-box="ai" ></span>
        </div>

        <!-- FRIENDS -->
        <div class="box friends1">
            <span data-box="friends1" ></span>
        </div>
        <div class="friends2">
            <span data-box="friends2" ></span>
        </div>
        <div class="box friends3">
            <span data-box="friends3" ></span>
        </div>  

        <!-- KIDS -->
        <div class="box kids">
            <span data-box="kids" ></span>
        </div>          
        <!-- PARENTS -->    
        <div class="box parents">
            <span data-box="parents" ></span>
        </div>          
        <!-- QUOTE -->    
        <div class="box quote">
            <span data-box="quote" ></span>
        </div>      
        <!-- BIRD 2 -->
        <div class="box bird2">
            <span data-box="box bird2" ></span>
        </div>        
    </div>



    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="" class="row meaningImg">
            <div class="background">                        
                <a href="../public/img/TALLPART1.png">
                  <img class="" src="http://arttreeoflife.com/public/img/TALLPART1.png" class="meaningImg">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So far your `animate` call is a Syntax Error.

Comment: @vinayakj Still not enough… the number of `{` and `}` don’t match.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle link with the complete code you have right now?

Comment: sure I will do that right now

Comment: @StefanGruenwald I can't get it to work on Jsfiddle because the image of the painting and the background is not coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got my code to work.

I kept my HTML the same but made a few changes to my jQuery.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".ganesh").offset().top,
}, 5000).animate({
    scrollLeft: $(".bird1").offset().left,
}, 5000).animate({
    scrollLeft: $(".saar").offset().left,
}, 5000).animate({
     scrollLeft: $(".anna").offset().left,
}, 5000).animate({
     scrollLeft: $(".friends1").offset().left,
}, 5000).animate({
     scrollLeft: $(".quote").offset().left,
}, 5000);
});
```

I think I just needed to fix my syntax a bit, and I was able to scroll to both parts of the screen from the first few lines of code, but it scrolled diagonally. To make it stop between each scroll I had to make a new animation. And this is why I think it worked.

If someone could explain this to me better please do I'm am not sure if I follow what is going on here or not.